# HTTP request and Response

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I'd like to make an HTTP request to a remote server and want to get reply back.

How can I connect to server and how to read the xml file response.

Comment: "Oh... I'm in such a hurry... I can't even be bothered to spell right."

Comment: What happened to "be nice to noobs"? Not everyone is an expert in English.

Comment: @sybreon: In the same vein, what happened to spell check? What happened to reviewing one's post before hitting submit? What happened to making an effort to be accurate? What happened to not calling n00bs, n00bs?

Comment: @kuldip: you didn't even say what kind of software you're using: web or thick client or console or service or Windows or Mac or Unix or ... I'll vote to close this if you don't edit it with details.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_server.asp for a simple example

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a good beginner tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) on AJAX / XMLHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a very simple test using telnet

```
telnet google.com 80
GET /path/to/file/index.html HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate a request to a web server and get a response back is to use a web browser - if you know the URL of the web service that is supplying the XML data, just navigate to that URL in the browser.  Note that this makes a few assumptions; for example, that the web service responds to GET requests (as opposed to POST, or other HTTP verbs).  If you clarify the scenario some more, we can provide more detailed guidance.